# Boolean value of fields in .csv file in Python

Tags: python, string, csv, boolean

I have a CSV file that I'm reading. One of the fields contains only 1s and 0s. I was under the assumption that Python will return a Boolean value of False for 0, but when my program reads a field whose value is 0, it returns True.

Is this because entries read in a .csv file are strings?

Comment: You could check this quickly yourself. Print out `repr(value)`; do you get `'0'` or `0`? The former is a string, and it will be treated as `True`.

Comment: @RobKennedy, that did the trick and answers my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is reading the value as the string `"0"`, which is a truthy value. Try using `int(field)` instead of the field itself.

Comment: Yes, I just checked using RobKennedy's answer, which helped. I tested your method, and that worked just fine. Thank you!